# Can't read element that was added using append

Tags: jquery

I am trying to learn jQuery.
Here I have problem can't read element that was added by `.append`

```
    <div id="team-builder">
        <div id="team-chosen"></div>
        <div id="member-input">
            <input type="text" class="input-field" id="name-input" placeholder="Insert name here..." />
            <button id="confirm-member">Add to the team</button>
            <button id="confirm-team" class="not-ready">Need 3 more people</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#confirm-team").click(function(){
            var tinput = $('#name-input').val();
            $("#team-chosen").append("<div class='member'>+tinput+</div>");

           if ( $("#team-chosen").hasClass("member") ) { 
              cmember = $('.member').length;
              console.log(cmember);
            }

            // reset input
            $('#name-input').val('');
            $(this).removeClass("ready");
            $(this).addClass("not-ready");
    });
});
```

That's the code, button click will add `<div class='member'>+tinput+</div>` then I need to count that how many members were added by input.

Comment: Aren't you missing some quotes? `$("#team-chosen").append("<div class='member'>+tinput+</div>");` should be `$("#team-chosen").append("<div class='member'>"+tinput+"</div>");`. Also `$("#team-chosen").hasClass("member")` checks if `#team-chosen` has the class `member`, it doesn't check if it has *children* with that class...

Comment: `if ( $("#team-chosen").hasClass("member") ) {` - But *does* that element have that class?  What specifically isn't working as expected?  Please provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem and indicate specifically what problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.

Comment: Why do the `if` check anyway? `cmember` will simply be 0 if there are no elements with the "member" class. You're not using the value except to log it, but if you were to use it, just check if it's > 0...

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace this code:

```js
if ( $("#team-chosen").hasClass("member") ) { // <= Will never be true
  cmember = $('.member').length;
  console.log(cmember);
}
```

With this one:

```js
if ( $("#team-chosen .member").length ) { 
    cmember = $('.member').length;
    console.log(cmember);
}
```

**Why?**

[hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/): "Determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class."

Your `#team-chosen` will never get the `.member` class added to it. It's the children inside it that will have the class `.member` that's why you need to rethink your selector value.

---

A somewhat cleaner approach:

```js
const cmembers = $("#team-chosen .member").length; 
      
if ( cmembers ) { 
  console.log(cmembers);
}
```